# ES6 best way to import React's named imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I was wondering which of the two way of importing React named imports ( `PropTypes` , `Component`) in ES6 is the best.

#### First

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
```

which would save a lot of typing specially on components that have lots of props to validate.

#### Second

```
import React form 'react';
```

and then calling them like `React.Component` when I want to use them.

Is there any **performance** difference between the two approaches or  should I just pick whichever **style** I am more comfortable with ?

Comment: *"should I just pick whichever style I am more comfortable with"* Yes. Any performance difference will be negligible compared to what the rest of your app is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there is near-zero performance differences.

For me, the main advantages to the later is maintaining namespace:
This is a contrived example, because you obviously wouldn't include lodash and underscore -

```
import { map } form 'lodash';
import { map } from 'underscore'; // oh no map-clash
```

vs

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
import underscore from 'underscore'; // lodash.map v underscore.map
```

However, I generally lean towards the destructured version (the `{}` version), because it "feels" tidier than these possibly big objects everywhere.

**EDIT**

One other thing worth noting, are more and more libraries are getting better at writing modules that can be imported as smaller parts of a larger whole - which works particularly well for ES6's import functionality.

For example, if you are only using `map` from lodash, importing like this:

```
import map from 'lodash/map';
```

instead of this:

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
```

will result in a much smaller final compiled file (if you have your browseifry/rollup/webpack/[insert flavour of the month] set up correctly) as it will only bring in the required code needed to execute map. Whereas the first one brings in all the things.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you prefer, but most importantly - **stay consistent**.

---

The community around React and the official docs prefer the second alternative, that's also my personal preference, because it is more descriptive.

```
import React from 'react';
```

and use it like

```
class Welcome extends React.Component { ... }
```